# Как удалить записи из таблицы одной командой?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc, sql

Не получается удалить записи в таблице! Нужно удалить все комментарии у которых `item_id=6`.
Этих комментарий штук 8. Пробую удалить таким образом:

```
IQueryable<Comment> query = (from del in db.Comments where del.item_id == 6 select del);
db.DeleteObject(query);//ругается тут
```

Но пишет что:

> Не удалось удалить объект, поскольку он не найден в ObjectStateManager.

однако, если я хочу удалить один комментарий, т.е. так:

```
Comment cquery = (from del in db.Comments where del.id == 4 select del).First();
```

то получается.
Как мне правильно написать, чтобы не применять `foreach` и подобные вещи, а удалить сразу все комментарии, одним sql запросом (или командой, как правильнее сказать)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = from com in db.Comments
             where com.item_id == 6
             select com;

foreach (Comment comment in query) { // тут будет 1 запрос на выборку из бд
     db.Comments.Remove(comment);
}

db.SaveChanges(); // тут будет  delete [dbo].[Comments] where ([Id] = 6)
```

То есть удаление всех комментариев с `item_id=6` произойдет с помощью одного SQL запроса

Comment: а у меня нет такого определения Remove

Comment: тогда foreach(comment in query){
   db.DeleteObject(query);
}
db.SaveChanges();

Comment: цикл foreach просто помечает обекты как удаленные, а SaveChanges уже удаляет их одним запросом

Comment: ааа, спасибо! я не знал)

Comment: Как-то это нелогично. Если мы помечаем несколько объектов к удалению, как система определит, что они были получены одним запросом? Она может только каждый из них удалить.

Answer (score 0):

А зачем foreach ? Можно же сделать так:

context.YourTable.RemoveRange(context.YourTable);
context.SaveChanges();